# Downgrading Scala 2.12.3 to Scala 2.10 in Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala

I currently have Scala 2.12.3 installed and wish to switch it to 2.10. How would I go about doing this in Eclipse? I could not find any guides on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in eclipse's settings -> Scala Compiler.

You can try this link,
http://scala-ide.org/blog/scala-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scala version used for any project by

right click on project->scala->set the scala installation

you will get list of scala versions supported